# How do you trigger landscape fullscreen in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, fullscreen

There are a million resources out there explaining that iOS browsers don't support the fullscreen web API.

But I know there is a way to do landscape fullscreen on iOS. See these examples:

- https://poki.com/en/g/stick-merge
- https://www.google.com/doodles/doodle-champion-island-games-begin

When you go to those pages, they tell you to rotate your phone to landscape, and once you do - the entire phone UI is gone. True fullscreen.

I just can't figure out what's the API for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Boy do I feel silly.

There is no API.

Just browse to any page on Safari iOS, rotate your phone to landscape, and bam, you're in fullscreen mode.